# Derivatives Trading Jargon

Tags: options, derivatives

Could you please help to understand trading jargon in this [tweet](https://twitter.com/m_paulmcnamara/status/1116611702512971779?s=21).

Thanks in advance.

For non twitter users: Bookie pushing 5-delta (strike of 8)  2 month TRY puts. 0.6%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current USDTRY is about 5.7. The jargon means this: The strike of a 2 month USD Call/ TRY put corresponding to a delta of 0.05 is 8, and it costs 0.6% of USD notional.

TRY to plunge is what might be implied!

Comment: That's a 40% depreciation in 2 months. The person who is "pushing" this investment is very pessimistic on Turkey's economy.

Comment: or he is gambling?  :)

Comment: TRY (Turkish yeni (new) lira) is the ISO code for Turkey's currency.